# "An invalid XML character" in RSS feed for question with unusual characters in it

Tags: bug, rss

The question [Special Characters introduced into the files when uploaded to SFTP using Blogical adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39870146) produces invalid XML when it's part of an RSS feed. The XML corresponding to the "special characters" section of the question text produces this error on http://www.xmlvalidation.com/:

> An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x10) was found in the element content of the document.

I found this because I have an RSS feed for various ssh-related tags. I eventually reduced the feed to [just the SFTP tag](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=sftp&sort=newest). The problem ought to be reproducible as long as the question remains among the results.

Edit: The question which was causing this problem has been edited, and I think the problematic character was removed.

Comment: Very strange, I was the one that edited it and I certainly didn't intend to change any characters in that payload, but looking at the edit history https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39870146/revisions  it did change them.  Stranger still if you look at side-by-side & side-by-side markdown they indicate different things have changed.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf That was your browser, I think. If I open https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39870146/edit/c1e5d1bb-b627-4fd9-9ef7-44f8c2343b06 in Firefox, the special characters get preserved. If I open it in Chromium, some of the special characters get removed (verified by copying and pasting from there to another application that shows the characters).

Comment: The characters in question are: [\u0010 - DATA LINK ESCAPE](//fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0010), [\u008F - SINGLE SHIFT THREE](//fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0010), [\u001D - INFORMATION SEPARATOR THREE](//fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0010), [\u0090 - DEVICE CONTROL STRING](//fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0010), and [\u0001 - START OF HEADING](//fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0010).